# How to make the mouse slower in KDE 4?

Tags: linux, mouse, debian, kde, kde-4

I have bought one of the new Logitech wireless mice for my laptop, but it seems too "fast" - a small movement results in massive movement on the screen, its much faster than the old corded mouse I am using with my desktop.

How can I make it slower in KDE 4.4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it's under the System Settings tool:

System Settings->Keyboard and Mouse->Mouse->Advanced->Pointer Acceleration.  Dial it up/down to accelerate/decelerate.